# Why does my Python code skips a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm building a guessing program for user's input in range 1 - 100.

Why does it skips the second while loop where I check user input and forward it. It goes straight with number 1

```
import random

nums_lasted = []
a = 0
while a < 101:
    nums_lasted.append(a)
    a += 1
secret_num = 1
while secret_num < 0 or secret_num > 100:
    try:
        secret_num = int(input("My number is"))
    except ValueError:
        print("No way that was an integer!")
guess_pc = 50
min = 50
max = 101
while True:
    print("Is it", guess_pc,"?")
    if guess_pc == secret_num:
        print("Easy")
        break
    elif guess_pc > secret_num:
        max = guess_pc
        nums_lasted.append(guess_pc)
        nums_lasted1 = [i for i in nums_lasted if i < guess_pc]
        nums_lasted = nums_lasted1
    elif guess_pc < secret_num:
        min = guess_pc
        nums_lasted.append(guess_pc)
        nums_lasted1 = [i for i in nums_lasted if i < guess_pc]
        nums_lasted = nums_lasted1
    guess_pc = random.choice(nums_lasted)
```

Comment: Hint: what is the truth value of `1 < 0 or  1 > 100`?

Comment: BTW, in Python you can do `while not 0 <= secret_number <= 100:`

Answer (score 3):

```
secret_num = 1
while secret_num < 0 or secret_num > 100:
```

You set `secret_num` to `1`. The `while` will only run when `secret_num` is less than 0 or grater than 100, so it will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Because the condition `secret_num < 0 or secret_num > 100` is false for `secret_num == 1`. 1 is definitely between 0 and 100. You should set `secret_number` to something larger than 100 for this to work as expected.

Comment: `secret_num < 0 or secret_num > 100` is false when `secret_num == 1`